# Pure CSS hover transition is jumpy (in Safari) when keeping image centered

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

Inspired by [Design Shack](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/imagehovers/index.html), I wanted to have some linkable photos zoom in slightly when hovered over. However, I want the animations to be centered, so it's like we're zooming in slightly.

In order to keep the image centered, I fiddled with top, left, margin-top, and margin-left to make it work. I'm not even sure *how* it works :-) but it works...

...except that the animation is actually kind of choppy and jumpy, at least in Safari - worst of all in Safari on 10.9.  (Firefox and Chrome do a better job though.)

Check out the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/MnHVk/1/

The salient piece:

```
.card img:hover {
    height:110%;
    width:110%;

    top:10%;
    left:-10%;
    margin-top:-10%;
    margin-left:5%;
}
```

Compare the jumpy animation to the version that doesn't try to center, here:
http://jsfiddle.net/MnHVk/2/

Can anybody think of any other way to do this hover animation that won't result in such a jumpy effect? Perhaps there's some other technique for adjusting the positioning so that when the image is hovered over, it moves smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use transform, it should render thru the GPU, and I think, smoothly

```
.card img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);

    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
}
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MnHVk/3/)

Comment: Aha, that was the start I needed.  I just needed to add transform-origin to 50% 50%, rather than trying to animate the top and left sides.  Result at: http://jsfiddle.net/MnHVk/5/

Comment: It's somehow strange that you need to add transform-origin 50% 50%; it should be the default value. Anyway, I can't test in Safari, so may be in Safari is necesary. I have restored your edition for completeness.